# Bit manipulation tool set

Tags: c++, template, library, bitwise, c++14

I made a tool set to facilitate bit manipulation as follows. Any comments are welcome, be it about the interface design, the implementation, or even the naming. Also, I want to make sure that the tool set is not lacking something for use-cases I failed to catch :-) Original code and unit tests can be found [here](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/Happy_Hacking_CXX/blob/master/hhxx/bit.hpp) and [here](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/Happy_Hacking_CXX/blob/master/test/bit.cpp).

```
/// The index is zero-based, starting from the least significant bit.
/// The most significant bit or sign bit is the head bit.

template <typename T>
constexpr unsigned num_bits(T = 0) {
  return sizeof(T) << 3;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr unsigned head_bit_idx(T = 0) {
  return num_bits<T>() - 1;
}

template <typename T>
T bit_flag(unsigned idx) {
  // since C++14, `1 << (num_bits<int> - 1)` is well-defined and makes `INT_MIN`
  return static_cast<T>(1) << idx;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr T head_bit_flag() {
  return static_cast<T>(1) << head_bit_idx<T>();
}

template <typename T>
bool test_bit(T x, unsigned idx) {
  return x & bit_flag<T>(idx);
}

template <typename T>
bool test_head_bit(T x) {
  return test_bit(x, head_bit_idx(x));
}

template <typename T>
T set_bit(T x, unsigned idx) {
  return x | bit_flag<T>(idx);
}

template <typename T>
T set_head_bit(T x) {
  return set_bit(x, head_bit_idx<T>());
}

template <typename T>
T clear_bit(T x, unsigned idx) {
  return x & ~bit_flag<T>(idx);
}

template <typename T>
T clear_head_bit(T x) {
  return clear_bit(x, head_bit_idx<T>());
}

template <typename T>
T flip_bit(T x, unsigned idx) {
  return x ^ bit_flag<T>(idx);
}

template <typename T>
T flip_head_bit(T x) {
  return flip_bit(x, head_bit_idx<T>());
}

template <typename T>
unsigned num_bits_set(T x) {
  unsigned cnt = 0;
  // behavior of signed type underflow is unspecified
  std::make_unsigned_t<T> v = x;
  while (v) {
    ++cnt;
    v &= v - 1;
  }
  return cnt;
}
```

Comment: What's the advantage of this over `std::bitset`?

Comment: @T.C. I don't actually need a bit stream, and `std::bitset` is a little heavy and inconvenient for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
constexpr unsigned num_bits(T = 0) {
  return sizeof(T) << 3;
}
```

For full generality, you should use `std::numeric_limits`. `numeric_limits<T>::digits` tells you the number of non-sign bits; `numeric_limits<T>::is_signed` tell you whether the type is signed so you can add 1 for the sign bit if needed. Your code is assuming that `CHAR_BIT == 8` and that `T` has no padding bits, neither of which is necessarily true.

`num_bits_set` is the popcount, and should really be implemented with `std::bitset::count()`, which is very efficiently implemented, possibly using a compiler intrinsic such as GCC's `__builtin_popcount()` (which in turn is compiled down to a single `popcnt` instruction where possible).

Comment: Yes. I should have used `CHAR_BIT` instead of hard-coded 8. But is there any advantage in using `std::numeric_limits` over `CHAR_BIT`? Also, `std::numeric_limits` may not be specialized for each arithmetic type. I think `sizeof(T)` takes padding bits into account. No? `std::bitset` doesn't seem to have a constructor for signed integer types. Guess I will have to cast it to its unsigned counterpart of the same size, as then use that to construct the `std::bitset`. I didn't know that `std::bitset::count()` may be highly optimized. Thanks for the info :-)

Comment: @Lingxi The point is that you *don't* want to consider padding bits. Also, `numeric_limits` is specialized for every arithmetic type - http://eel.is/c++draft/limits#limits.numeric-2

Comment: Learned a lot from you, as always. Gonna update the code~

Comment: `std::bitset::count()` is not `constexpr` specified :-( This isn't much a problem. Just a little pity.

Answer (score 3):

False optimization (and makes it hard to read).

```
template <typename T>
constexpr unsigned num_bits(T = 0) {
  return sizeof(T) << 3;
}
```

This should be `sizeof(T) * 8` that's so much easier to read. And if it quicker to shift that is what the compiler will actually do. Don't try and outsmart the compiler the only thing that will is happen is that you will outsmart yourself.

Also its not actually 8. TO be compliant and accurate use `CHAR_BIT`.

This is a bit inefficient.

```
template <typename T>
unsigned num_bits_set(T x) {
  unsigned cnt = 0;
  // behavior of signed type underflow is unspecified
  std::make_unsigned_t<T> v = x;
  while (v) {
    ++cnt;
    v &= v - 1;
  }
  return cnt;
}
```

You are using a runtime loop (over each bit). You could use a compile time loop over each byte. Because the number of bits set for each specific value for a byte it is easy to pre-calculate.

Note: For each byte there are only `CHAR_BIT` number of bits (usually 8). Which is 256 values. So you can swap space for time here for a single byte.

```
unsigned num_bits_set_count_value[] = {
0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4,  // 000-015
1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5,  // 016-031
1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5,  // 032-047
2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6,  // 048-063
1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5,  // 064-079
2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6,  // 080-095
2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6,  // 096-111
3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7,  // 112-127
// ---
1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5,  // 128-143
2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6,  // 144-159
2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6,  // 160-175
3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7,  // 176-191
2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6,  // 192-207
3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7,  // 208-223
3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7,  // 224-239
4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 8}; // 240-255

// Use compile time meta program
// to unwind a multi byte value into a set of adds
// these will all be inlined.
template <int x>
unsigned num_bits_set_count(char const* byteStream) {
    return num_bits_set_count_value[*byteStream]
         + num_bits_set_count<x - 1>(byteStream + 1);
}
template<> unsigned num_bits_set_count<0>(char const*) {return 0;}

template <typename T>
unsigned num_bits_set(T x) {
   return num_bits_set_count<sizeof(T)>(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&x));
}
```

Overall its fine. But you can get the same functionality from using `std::bitset` and its more readable.

```
 int a {86};
 std::bitset<sizeof(a) * CHAR_BIT>   x(a);
 // test bit 5
 x[5]

 // set bit 5
 x[5] |= 1;

 // reset bit 5
 x[5] ^= 1;
```

Comment: The false optimization and `CHAR_BIT` is a nice catch. Just [updated](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/Happy_Hacking_CXX/commit/fc5ce35a71a8cb21382a54c2fb19c0929ac64620) the library code. The optimized `num_bits_set()` is inspiring, but a little too much. I don't think I will actually use it. Besides, it does memory access quite a bit. This overhead should be taken into account. As to `std::bitset`,  I don't actually need a bit stream, and `std::bitset` is a little heavy and inconvenient for me.

Comment: `Besides, it does memory access quite a bit`: It fits in a single cache line. So multiple access is no slower than a single access. It's also how all the `is<X>(char)` like `isspace()` etc work. It will be your fastest technique. `std::bitset` is **NOT** a stream. its a very simple wrapper usually around a long (or multiple longs if size > 32). So it would add no cost and simplify your code.

Answer (score 2):

Overall I think this is a really good straightforward implementation. It's easy to understand. Here are some improvements that I see:

## Const Correctness

You should be making all of the parameters `const`. In all cases you're either returning a copy or the parameter is an index. Marking them as `const` can let the compiler do optimizations in some cases.

## Use of `head`

What's the purpose of special casing the `head` bit? Aside from the case where it's the sign bit, are there enough cases to warrant making it special? (I can believe there are, it's just not immediately obvious to me.) I tend to use bit manipulation on flags, and not so much on numbers. (I did actually use `std::sign_bit()` for the first time just this week, though!) If there are a lot of cases where users of your functions will need to get/set the high bit, then keep it. Otherwise, I'm not sure it adds much.

## Naming

Overall, the naming is great. I much prefer `set` and `clear` to `set` and `reset`. The word `reset` does not trigger clearing a bit in my mind.

If you are going to keep the `head` functions, you might consider a different name for `head`. I've never heard the high bit called the `head` bit. You could rename them as `high_bit_idx()`, `high_bit_flag()` or something similar. If the purpose is mainly for dealing with sign bits on numeric values you could name them `sign_bit_idx()` and `sign_bit_flag()`, etc.

## What's missing?

I've only run into a few other things that might be useful, and these are definitely not 80% cases. I've seen cases where you need to determine the position of the first (highest) bit set. So you could have a function like `find_highest_set_bit(T x)` or something like that.

It could be useful to extend this to a bit stream, where you handle an unlimited number of bits, rather than just the bits in the type you're dealing with. That's more complicated, of course. I've done this before when dealing with image compression.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed review. It does help! 1) I made all functions constexpr. As such, it's unnecessary to further const-qualify the parameters. 2) The `head` family is mainly a convenient shorthand to save you from typing `num_bits() - 1` or `head_bit_idx()`. I guess I will just keep them along. 3) After a second thought, `head` IS a bad name. It doesn't following any existing practice. I renamed it to MSB which is widely known as a shorthand for most significant bit. 4) As to bit stream, I think `std::bitset` or `std::vector<bool>` will do it :-)

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Yeah, I forgot about `constexpr`. Good point. Glad it helped at least a little!